# Handling arbitrary queries in NPoco

Tags: c#, npoco

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here, how can I run a query through NPoco and retrieve an arbitrary number of potentially differently typed values as a result.

**Example**

Say I have a table that looks like this:

```
|-------------------|------------|
| ID    |    AMOUNT | DATE       |
|-------------------|------------|
| 1     |      2300 | 01/02/2014 |
| 2     |       400 | 03/02/2014 |
| 3     |      1200 | 06/02/2014 |
| 4     |       950 | 06/02/2014 |
|-------------------|------------|
```

I want to query this table with the following (MSSQL):

```
SELECT
MAX(DATE) AS MOST_RECENT_ORDER_DATE, SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_AMT_OF_ORDERS
FROM
ORDERS
```

So I figure I'd use code similar to the following, where `db` is an NPoco `Database` object.

```
var result = db.Query(<query string>);
```

The problem is NPoco's Query method requires a type parameter and I'm not sure what to give it.  The problem is the two values actually have different types, one will be a `DateTime` and the other will be an `int`.  I tried using the following:

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> result;
result = db.Query<Dictionary<string, object>>(queryString).ToList();
```

But I can't figure out the syntax to access/use the results, and it all just seems very clunky and I'm sure I must have gone about this the wrong way.

To summarise:

**How can I use NPoco to run a query returning columns of different (arbitrary) types, and then access and use those values?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track. The query returns only one row so you can simply fetch the first dictionary from the result:

```
result = db.Query<Dictionary<string, object>>(queryString)
var dictionary = result.First();
```

Then you can get the objects using the names from the query:

```
dictionary["MOST_RECENT_ORDER_DATE"]
dictionary["TOTAL_AMT_OF_ORDERS"]
```

Afterwards you can simply convert the objects to your desired data types. (eg. using [Convert methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Convert_methods(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved it for me.  I knew it would be something simple!

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `db.FirstOfDefault<Dictionary<string, object>>(queryString)` instead of `db.Query` and then simply get your values from the dictionary (the keys are the column names).

Comment: Actually SingleOrDefault is better if you are expecting (and can handle) only one.  Then his original code would work properly.